# Android Wear - как отлаживать часы по Bluetooth?

Tags: android-studio, android-wear

Телефон и часы в режиме отладки
Телефон подключен к PC через USB
Часы  LG у них только Bluetooth (включен режим отладки)

```
 adb forward tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub
 adb connect localhost:4444
```

Проблема состоит в том что в AndroidStudio часы  не определяются (только телефон или эмуляторы) потому что часы не подключены  по usb а Bluetooth на PC нету.

Как запустить модуль wear на реальных часах ?